# Fade images without black transfer between them - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

> http://www.chooseyourtelescope.com/

When you hover the logos buttons (moon, planet, etc...) it does background1>BLACK>background2.

I would like to get directly background1>Background2 and keep the fade effect.

*(I don't know anything about Javascript, I found this code below on Stackoverflow)*

Here is the code for the moon button:

**HTML**

```
  <div class="top-logos-home" id="top-logos-lune-front" >
      <img src="logo-moon.png" alt="MOON">
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.image-home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(Frontpage.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display:inline;
    top:0;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(function(){
    var $body = $('.image-home');
    $('#top-logos-moon-front').hover(function(){
        $body.fadeOut('slow',function(){
          $body.css('background-image', 'url("Frontpage-moon.jpg")').fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }, function() {
        $body.css('background-image', '')
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using the **opacity** property. Now its working perfectly.

**HTML**

```
<img id="background-moon-front" class="hover-backgrounds" src="Frontpage-moon.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
.hover-backgrounds {
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 0.6s linear;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#top-logos-lune-front").hover(function (e) {
    $("#background-moon-front").css("opacity", "1");
    }, function() {
        $("#background-moon-front").css("opacity", "0")
    })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have create a jsFiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/h0f6y58z/

Html

```
<div class="top-logos-home" id="top-logos-lune-front">
    <img class="image-1 image" src="http://s.hswstatic.com/gif/singapura-cat.jpg" />
    <img class="image-2 image" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/424484505915621376/EOwsjaMZ_400x400.png" />
</div>
```

css

```
.image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(Frontpage.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    top:0;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.image-2').hide();

    $('.top-logos-home').mouseover(function () {
        $('.image-1').fadeOut();
        $('.image-2').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

All this does is checks to see if the mouse enters the div and if so, we will fadeout the first image and fade in the second image. You could use first image hide and last image show if you would prefer

Like so

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.image-2').hide();

    $('#top-logos-lune-front').mouseover(function () {
        $('.image').first().fadeOut();
        $('.image').last().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks i'll try it and let you know. Just can you edit id="top-logos-lune-front" in id="top-logos-moon-front" please.